# Get Swift method name of Objective-C selector in runtime

Tags: objective-c, swift

Is there a way from either Objective-C runtime or Swift runtime to get the Swift name of given Objective-C selector (after renaming)? I’m trying to generate a table of:

> Swift method name -> Objective-C method name

For use later (in scripting binding).

I’m considering any way.

Answer (score 0):

there is a method that does almost this thing, but not quite:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/javascriptcore/jsexport

```
#define JSExportAs(PropertyName, Selector) \
    @optional Selector __JS_EXPORT_AS__##PropertyName:(id)argument; @required Selector

#endif
```

then one can fetch "decorated" with macro like that methods with objective-c runtime.